# Unwanted Foreign Key Constraint in Entity Framework 6.1 Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

My EF project has a `Day` class, a `WeekEnd` class and a `Week` class in my model. I marked the classes with `[InverseProperty]` and `[Required]` attributes:

```
public class Day
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DayId { get; set; }

    public DateTime UtcDayStart { get; set; }

    public string DayName { get; set; }

    public int ISOWeekNumber {get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Days")]
    public virtual Week Week { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Days")]
    public virtual WeekEnd WeekEnd { get; set; }
}

public class WeekEnd
{
    Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int WeekEndId { get; set; }

    public DateTime UtcWeekEndStart { get; set; }

    public int ISOWeekNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [InverseProperty("WeekEnd")]
    public virtual Week Week { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("WeekEnd")]
    public virtual ICollection<Day> Days { get; set; }
}

public class Week
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int WeekId { get; set; }

    public DateTime UtcWeekStart { get; set; }

    public int ISOWeekNumber { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Week")]
    public virtual WeekEnd WeekEnd { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Week")]
    public virtual ICollection<Day> Days { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that SQL Server won't let me insert `Day` table data with a `Null` for `WeekEnd_WeekEndId`. And since not all days of the week belong to week ends that is a problem for me.

The Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO [database].[dbo].[Days] (DayId, UtcDayStart, ISOWeekNumber,
DayName, WeekEnd_WeekEndId, Week_WeekId)
VALUES ('3', '1/3/2005 12:00 AM', '1', 'Monday', '', '1')
```

The SQL Server error message is:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Days_dbo.WeekEnds_WeekEnd_WeekEndId". The conflict occurred in database "database", table "dbo.WeekEnds", column 'WeekEndId'.

How can I set the attributes or possibly add a foreign key column (or columns) to make the code-first migration not create that foreign key constraint between `Days` and `WeekEnds`?

EDIT:

So after working on this and trying different FluentAPI statements and attributes I think the model is fine. It is the SQL Server `INSERT` statement that won't work. If I do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO [database].[dbo].[Days] (DayId, UtcDayStart, ISOWeekNumber,
DayName, Week_WeekId)
VALUES ('3', '1/3/2005 12:00 AM', '1', 'Monday', '1')
```

and then do an `UPDATE` like the following on those days that actually belong to a `WeekEnd`:

```
UPDATE [database].[dbo].[Days] SET WeekEnd_WeekEndId = 'X'  WHERE DayId ='Y'
```

Then my table has `Null` values (like I want) for `WeekEnd_WeekEndId` for Monday through Friday days.

I'm not sure that this would qualify as an answer though because I'm new to this. So I will let someone else propose an answer.

Comment: your question doesn't make sense.  you created a navigation property between `Days` and `WeekEnd`, yet you don't want it to have a FK?

Comment: Ok well I want a Nav property but nullable. If a day is not Sat or Sun there would be no WeekEnd property.

Comment: but you didn't make it nullable in your model.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Lol, this sentence *And since not all days of the week belong to week ends that is a problem for me* could apply to many people in many different contexts. It surely does to me sometimes. But, serious, can't your days just have a property, such as DayType( week, or weekend)? You can always produce weeks/weekends from there.

Comment: Great point! I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure the relationships as a `0..many` instead of a `1..many`, you will need to adjust the model.  The easiest way to do this would be with the FluentAPI.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

    modelBuilder.Entity<Week>()
                .HasMany<Day>(w => w.Days)
                .WithOptional(d => d.Week);

    modelBuilder.Entity<WeekEnd>()
                .HasMany<Day>(we => we.Days)
                .WithOptional(d => d.WeekEnd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I will try it. Would I need to remove any attributes?

Comment: One more question. Since every Day would belong to a Week do I need that first statement?

Comment: no, if you supply a week for every day, then it's not necessary,  I thought you were wanting to add to either the Week or WeekEnd, not one or both, when I wrote the code there.

Comment: Adding the statement didn't change the DBMigration at all. There were no statements in either the Up() or Down() method as result of the change.

Comment: I'm not really sure why that would be the case; maybe in this situation you need `.WithOptionalPrincipal()`?